# Trying to add click event on the prepend element:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

Trying to redirect to different page on click of image

```
 $('.grid').prepend('<div id="new" style="width:50px;background-color:#1879A9;padding-left:3px;margin-top:10px"><a href="#somelink"><img id="test" src="#somesource"></a></div>');
```

Tried the below code:

```
$('.grid').on('click', '#test', function() {
      alert("test"); //It didnt work.
});
```

Comment: Please add more details. We don't know your DOM. Here you have add an event if the user click on an element with the id `test` inside the element with the class `grid`...

Comment: Note that you should change the HTML you prepend to use classes, not an `id`, as you will end up appending multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid. That way you can also you a CSS stylesheet instead of inline styling, which should be avoided where possible

Comment: And if you use a `<a>` element with a valid href it's useless to add an event listener on this. The click event on the link will be triggered first.

Comment: It works as expected! [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o98pusr1/), Although it's not recommended to use Ids while using prepend use **class** instead of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I think you just create multiple same ID elements.

Change using ID to class, it should work fine.

**Edited**

Modified base on asker's comment

```js
$('.grid').each(function(event){
    if($(this).find('.test').length > 0) return false;
    var _html = '<div style="width:50px;background-color:#1879A9;padding-left:3px;margin-top:10px"><a class="link" href="'+$(this).data('url')+'"><img class="test" src="'+$(this).data('image')+'"></a></div>';
    var new_node = $(_html);
    $(this).prepend(new_node);
    new_node.find('.test').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr('src'));
        // redirect here
        // window.location.href = $(this).parent().attr('href');
    })
})
```

```css
.grid{

width:40px;
height:40px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid" data-url="x.x.x" data-image="http://x.x.x"></div>
<br/>
<div class="grid" data-url="y.y.y" data-image="http://y.y.y"></div>
<br/>
<div class="grid" data-url="z.z.z" data-image="http://z.z.z"></div>
<br/>
<div class="grid" data-url="a.a.a" data-image="http://a.a.a"></div>
```

Comment: Other than the whitespace, what exactly have you changed?

Comment: No change. I think the code is fine, so I just made an example.

Comment: In which case this isn't an answer. If it doesn't work for the OP there must be an underlying issue which this does not address

Comment: OK. I just think make it work is the answer. What should I do now? delete this answer?

Comment: That would probably be best

Comment: Hey hi.. ".grid" is an inbuilt sharepoint class.  I am trying to prepend my div element to it with image tag. I want o redirect to another page on click of that image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$('.grid').on('click', window.location.href = 'page_url');
```

Comment: 1) This will redirect immediately, before the user clicks the `.grid` 2) the event handler needs to be delegated as the content is appended after the DOM loads 3) the OP has made no indication that they want to redirect the page anyway

Comment: Hey hi.. ".grid" is an inbuilt sharepoint class.  I am trying to prepend my div element to it with image tag. I want o redirect to another page on click of that image.

Answer (score 0):

First you've to use class insted of id , (semantically error when same id for multiple element )

also to redirect to your page when clicking on the image , 
first prevent default action when click on the grid , so it wont redirect when clicking on link directly .

then get the link of the a parent tag image and perfom redirect programticly using $(this).parent("a").attr("href"); `window.location.href`

See below snippet :

```js
$('.grid').prepend(
   '<div class="new" style="width:50px;background-color:#1879A9;padding-left:3px;margin-top:10px"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com"><img class="test" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShuHaRYzsoiz_KpVL5Ite65oK_ILy3p1b5vrZ996D1HFKdAS64"></a></div>');
    
$('.grid').on('click', '.test', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var urlRedirect = $(this).parent("a").attr("href");
  console.log("redirecting to ..."+ urlRedirect);
  // this will redirect after 2 sec
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = urlRedirect;
  },2000)
  
  
});
```

```css
.test {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: is this helpfull or not :)