# How can I add an event after inserting the element through jquery async function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable

I'm new to vue. I wanted to add an event after inserting the element through datatable function called **initComplete**. I've tried this code but it's not working.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    created: function () {
        $("#data-table").DataTable({
            initComplete: function() {
                let button = "<a class='btn btn-primary upload' @click='upload()' href='#'>Upload</a>";
                $(".dataTables_filter > label").prepend(button);
            }
        });
    },
    methods: {
        upload: function() {
            console.log('Upload');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to add click event on the prepend element:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793285/trying-to-add-click-event-on-the-prepend-element)

Comment: @Dani If jquery yes but I'm using vuejs.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't know anything about VUE ^^

Comment: @Dani No worries man. Thanks though.

Comment: A wild guess. try renaming `created` method to `mounted`.

Comment: @Kharel I will try this. Thanks!